# UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps when using react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

While using the react-select, I got this warning `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended`.
It was not happening when i using react older version.

However i followed this site https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3720?fbclid=IwAR3PDuGWJPxetMkO0Nm7gT7My_nb92VZp-cX5eVmgB7h9KU9z8nIgN-oyRo and i know this issue has been fixed but why i still having this warning.

my `react version` is **16.13.1** and `react-select` is **3.1.0**

```
const SelectProvince = ({ provinces }) => {
    const arrayProvince = React.useContext(DataContext);

    const [province, setProvince] = useState([]);
    const [selectProvince, setSelectProvince] = useState([]);
    const [isCheck, setIsCheck] = useState(false)


    useEffect(() =>{
        if(province.length !== 0){
            const segmentProvince = arrayProvince.filter((val) =>val.Province === province.label);
            setSelectProvince(segmentProvince);
            setIsCheck(true);
        }

    }, [province, arrayProvince]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Select Province</h2>
            <Select
                onChange={setProvince}
                options={ provinces }
                placeholder="Select Province...."
                isSearchable
            />
            {
            (isCheck) ? 
                (<Population provinceData = {selectProvince} /> ) 
                :(null)
            } 

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `i know this issue has been fixed` some instances of it have, [some have not](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4094). You'll just have to wait for the remaining issues to be fixed before updating to React 17 (which doesn't exist yet anyway).